# Angular check if array contains object with specific variable value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using angular and I have an array of Objects let's say `Item(SmallItem, Bollean, Boolean)` and in my code I add elements to this array by pushing, like for example:

```
this.Items.push(new Item(smallItem, false, true));
```

However, I would like to push an `Item` if and only if item with the same `smallItem` does not exist in `Items`. How do I go about it?

Comment: You can use this.Items.find(x=>x.smallItems==whatever) (return undefined if not find it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply go back to the basic and do something along thoses lines :

```
const itemToAdd = new Item(smallItem, false, true);
if(this.Items.findIndex((item) => item.smallItem === itemToAdd.smallItem) < 0) {
    this.Items.push(itemToAdd);
}
```

or if you don't want to create the Item if it is not added :

```
if(this.Items.findIndex((item) => item.smallItem === smallItemToAdd) < 0) {
    this.Items.push(new Item(smallItemToAdd, false, true););
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the items afterward with smallItem in it like

```
Items.forEach((index,item)=>{
if(item.smallItem){
Items.splice(index,1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

an other approach could be:

```
var find = false;

for (let item of Items) {
// same smallItem value
if(item.smallItem) {
find = true;
}
}

if(!find) {
this.Items.push(new Item(smallItem, false, true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```js
let items = [
  { name: 'Item 1', booleanA: true, booleanB: true },
  { name: 'Item 2', booleanA: true, booleanB: true },
  { name: 'Item 3', booleanA: true, booleanB: true },
  { name: 'Item 4', booleanA: true, booleanB: true },
  { name: 'Item 5', booleanA: true, booleanB: true }
];

function addItemIfNotAlreadyPresent(itemToAdd) {
  let itemAlreadyExist = items.find(
    item => item.name === itemToAdd.name && item.booleanA === itemToAdd.booleanA && item.booleanB === itemToAdd.booleanB
  );
  if(!itemAlreadyExist) {
    items.push(itemToAdd);
  }
}

let itemAlreadyPresent = { name: 'Item 1', booleanA: true, booleanB: true };
addItemIfNotAlreadyPresent(itemAlreadyPresent);
console.log('Items after trying to add itemAlreadyPresent: ', items);

let itemNotPresent = { name: 'Item 6', booleanA: true, booleanB: true };
addItemIfNotAlreadyPresent(itemNotPresent);
console.log('Items after trying to add itemNotPresent: ', items);
```